# Spark MLlib collaborative filtering

Tags: apache-spark, collaborative-filtering

I am building a recommender system for implicit data in Spark using MLlib. I was trying to find a already implemented function to make recommendations to users not seeing during training and I could find anything. Does anybody knows if such a function exist ? otherwise anybody has any advise on how too implemented it efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

There is no function for this. In fact it's not really feasible to make on-the-fly recommendations given the simple RDD-based model you get from MLlib. You can see an implementation in this blog post, at http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/03/why-apache-spark-is-a-crossover-hit-for-data-scientists/ :

```
def recommend(questionID: Int, howMany: Int = 5): Array[(String, Double)] = {
  // Build list of one question and all items and predict value for all of them
  val predictions = model.predict(tagHashes.map(t => (questionID,t._1)))
  // Get top howMany recommendations ordered by prediction value
  val topN = predictions.top(howMany)(Ordering.by[Rating,Double](_.rating))
  // Translate back to tags from IDs
  topN.map(r => (tagHashes.lookup(r.product)(0), r.rating))
}
```

The `lookup` makes it very slow though. To implement the recommendation rapidly (like <10ms) you would have to coalesce the RDD into an in-core representation.

However if you just need batch recommendations, then an approach like the above can be made efficient with joins.